# Let $z=xy+f(\frac yx) $. Show $z$ satisfies the partial differential eq. $x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=2xy$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose that $f: R\rightarrow R$ is differentiable and $z=xy+f(\frac yx)  $, $(x,y)\in R^2, x\neq 0.$ 
Show $z$ satisfies the partial differential equation:

$$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=2xy$$

From my understanding I differentiate $z$ with respect to some variable, but in this case I'm not sure what it is?

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = y + f'(\frac{y}{x}).\frac{-y}{x^2}$ (treating y as constant)

$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = x + f'(\frac{y}{x}).\frac{1}{x}$ (treating x as constant)

---

$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = xy + f'(\frac{y}{x}).\frac{-y}{x}$

$ y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = xy + f'(\frac{y}{x}).\frac{y}{x}$

---

$x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 2xy$

Comment: This is wrong, you can not write $$f'(\frac{y}{x})$$ and so on.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner No, you are wrong, you definitely can write it as $f'$, much the same as $\partial_{x}(f(x-y)) = af'(ax-by)$.

Comment: Ok, i think it is not so, since you will need a partial derivative, but my time is to valuable to discuss with you.

Comment: What do you think what is the meaning of $$f'(\frac{y}{x})$$? Differentiating with respect to $$x$$ or $$y$$ or both?

Comment: We are differentiating $f(\frac{y}{x})$ with respect to $\frac{y}{x}$ in both the cases, then differentiating $\frac{y}{x}$ with respect to $x$ first and then w.r.t $y$. So $f'(\frac{y}{x}) = \frac{d}{d(\frac{y}{x})}.f(\frac{y}{x})$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner. If $u(x,y) = f(v(x,y))$ then
$$\begin{align}
\partial_x u(x,y) &= f'(v(x,y)) \, \partial_x v(x,y) \\
\partial_y u(x,y) &= f'(v(x,y)) \, \partial_y v(x,y) \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Ok, this is not what was written here!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner. Yes, it is, with $v(x,y) = y/x$ and $\partial_x v(x,y) = -y/x^2$ and $\partial_y v(x,y) = 1/x.$

Answer (score 0):

We get $$xy-\frac{y}{x}f_x(\frac{y}{x})+xy+\frac{y}{x}f_y(\frac{y}{x})$$ and if $$f_x=f_y$$ we get $$2xy$$